# SPGridView PageIndexChanging does not hit when debugging

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, spgridview, gridview

I have a SP grid view which has loads data in a IList (data added to iList from DB).
When the pager pagination arrows "< >" are clicked the pager sometimes loads the same set.
When I tried to debug the "myGridView_PageIndexChanging" doesn't get hit.
Any reason why?
And what would be a better approach for this?

Code I have is:

1)
SPDataGrid:

```
<SharePoint:SPGridView ID="myGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowSorting="false" OnRowDataBound="myGridView_RowDataBound" >
```

pager:

```
<SharePoint:SPGridViewPager ID="myGridViewPager" runat="server" GridViewId="myGridView" Visible="false">
```

2)
On page load I have set code as:

```
myIList = MethdToGenerateMyIList();

myGridView.AllowPaging = true;
myGridView.PageSize = 10;
myGridView.PageIndexChanging += myGridView_PageIndexChanging;

memberGridView.DataSource = myIList;
memberGridView.DataBind();
```

3)
The page index changing method is:

```
private void myGridView_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            myGridView.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
            myGridView.DataSource = myIList;
            myGridView.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**method 1)**

asp.net

```
<asp:SPGridView ID="myGridView" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" GridLines="None" 
        OnPageIndexChanging="myGridView_PageIndexChanging" PageSize="10" ShowHeader="False" ShowFooter="False" />
```

c#

onload

```
myIList = MethdToGenerateMyIList();
memberGridView.DataSource = myIList;
memberGridView.DataBind();
```

gridview event

```
private void myGridView_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        myGridView.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        myGridView.DataSource = myIList;
        myGridView.DataBind();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

**Method 2)**

instead of asp.net, as you tried todo in .cs codebehind:

asp.net

```
<SharePoint:SPGridView ID="myGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowSorting="false" OnRowDataBound="myGridView_RowDataBound" >
```

.cs onload:

```
myIList = MethdToGenerateMyIList();

myGridView.AllowPaging = true;
myGridView.PageSize = 10;
myGridView.PageIndexChanging += new EventHandler(myGridView_PageIndexChanging);

memberGridView.DataSource = myIList;
memberGridView.DataBind();
```

grid view event

```
private void myGridView_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        myGridView.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        myGridView.DataSource = myIList;
        myGridView.DataBind();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the Reply I took the Method 2. And additionally set the page template to null. Works !